# Can I make cURL fail with an exitCode different than 0 if the HTTP status code is not 200?

Tags: curl, stdout, exit-code, http-status-code-500

I was always assuming that when curl got an HTTP 500 response it was returning an exit code that meant failure (!= 0), but that seems to be **not** the case.

Is there a way I can I make cURL fail with an exitCode different than 0 if the HTTP status code is not 200? I know I can use `-w "%{http_code}"` but that puts it in STDOUT, not as the exit code (besides, I'm also interested in capturing the output, which I don't want to redirect to a file, but to the screen).

Comment: Anyone getting here long after 2021/02/15: please note that a flag was added to curl that does *exactly* that - see https://superuser.com/a/1626376/25173 below. Of course, make sure your curl version is >= 7.76.0.

Comment: It's 2022 now, and (per my example) the latest LTS Jenkins docker includes this.

Comment: how is jenkins related to my question?

Comment: Not related at all, it was an example (showing that the current versions of images tend to include this curl version).

Comment: @noamtm I am currently struggling with a page returning "301 Moved Permanently" which is considered "fine" even with`--fail`, so this really buys nothing.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Most of the answers provided so far will not print the HTTP response body in case an HTTP request fails.

If you would like to print the response body as well, even if the exit code is non-zero due to the HTTP request failing: provided you have curl v7.76 or newer, simply use [`curl --fail-with-body`](https://superuser.com/a/1626376/215321).

For older versions of curl, try this:

```sh
curlf() {
  OUTPUT_FILE=$(mktemp)
  HTTP_CODE=$(curl --silent --output $OUTPUT_FILE --write-out "%{http_code}" "$@")
  if [[ ${HTTP_CODE} -lt 200 || ${HTTP_CODE} -gt 299 ]] ; then
    >&2 cat $OUTPUT_FILE
    return 22
  fi
  cat $OUTPUT_FILE
  rm $OUTPUT_FILE
}
```

Comment: Sadly, 7.76 did not reach macos, which seem to still use 7.65.1

Comment: If that's an option, you can use the GNU variants of such command-line tools. E. g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332/176024

Comment: Note that this function does not clean up the temporary output file on error.

Comment: For the record, the proper way to clean up temporary files is to use a `trap`; try `trap 'rm -f $OUTPUT_FILE; exit' EXIT ERR INT` (maybe also add other signals; to be perfectly candid, you should also [avoid upper case for your private variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts))

Answer (score 552):

`curl --fail` does part of what you want:

from [`man curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> **`-f, --fail`**
>
> (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts. In normal cases when an HTTP server fails to deliver a document, it returns an HTML document stating so (which often also describes why and more). This flag will prevent curl from outputting that and return error 22.
>
> This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).

But it blocks output to the screen.

Comment: So which parts of it does it do and not do?

Comment: @rogerdpack tl;dr it does return nonzero when it detects a bad response, but it wouldn't let OP capture the response

Comment: This doesn't catch HTTP 301 Move Permanently. curl still gave exit code 0.

Comment: @wisbucky 301 isn't an error, it's a redirection status code.  Errors are 4xx and 5xx status codes.

Comment: @wisbucky to exit nonzero on HTTP error codes *and* handle HTTP redirects correctly use `curl -f -L` and see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474690/is-there-a-way-to-follow-redirects-with-command-line-curl) for details on what `-L` does.

Comment: This is only of limited usefulness, especially if checking for a running endpoint in a script is only part of a chain of command sequences. The issue here is that we don't want to necessarily exit on error, but rather be able to return accordingly from a check function inside a script. A proper check on the `%{http_code}` is in this scenario still the best option. Solutions for that exist already as answers, albeit only basic variants.

Answer (score 141):

If you just want to display the contents of the curled page, you can do this:

```bsh
STATUSCODE=$(curl --silent --output /dev/stderr --write-out "%{http_code}" URL)

if test $STATUSCODE -ne 200; then
    # error handling
fi
```

This writes the page's content to STDERR while writing the HTTP status code to STDOUT, so it can be assigned to the variable *STATUSCODE*.

Comment: How about if I want to output the response on failure *(non 200)*, but return a non `0` status code from the script?

Comment: @Justin: What about `if [ "$statuscode" -ne 200 ]; then exit "$statuscode"; fi` ?

Comment: @ghoti: Only unsigned 8-bit exit codes are supported, so that could get a little confusing.

Comment: Ah, right -- and codes will wrap at 8 bits, so error 404 becomes exit value 148, 500 becomes 244.  Confusing indeed!  :-)

Comment: As a slight variation, this captures the code in a variable while redirecting the response to stdout, not stderr: `{ code=$(curl ... as above ...); } 2>&1` The trick is `{ ... } 2>&1` that allows redirecting, while not spawning a different shell as `( ... )` would.

Comment: similarly, you could pipe to `awk` rather than wrapping it in a script: `curl -w '\n%{http_code}' --silent  $URL | awk 'END { exit !was200 } { was200=0 ; print prev ; prev = $0 } /^200$/ { was200=1 }'`

Comment: Great answer. This seems to be the only way to get both the error exit code and the server response (which might include more details). Only thing I found is that it should accept all 2xx status codes as success, e.g. `if [ $(($STATUSCODE/100)) -ne 2 ]; then exit $STATUSCODE; fi`

Comment: I encourage you to use lower case shell variables when you don't intent to `export` them.

Answer (score 118):

Use `--fail-with-body`. This will cause `curl` to exit with status code 22 when response code is >=400.

Note though that this flag is brand new <sup>(as of 2021/02/15)</sup>, and was added in version 7.76.0, which postdates [@rampion's answer](https://superuser.com/a/657174/65696). Thus it might not be available on your system.

https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

> ### --fail-with-body
>
> (HTTP) Return an error on server errors where the HTTP response code
> is 400 or greater). In normal cases when an HTTP server fails to
> deliver a document, it returns an HTML document stating so (which
> often also describes why and more). This flag will still allow curl to
> outputting and save that content but also to return error 22.
>
> This is an alternative option to -f, --fail which makes curl fail for
> the same circumstances but without saving the content.
>
> See also -f, --fail. Added in 7.76.0.
>
> ### -f, --fail
>
> (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is
> mostly done to enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts.
> In normal cases when an HTTP server fails to deliver a document, it
> returns an HTML document stating so (which often also describes why
> and more). This flag will prevent curl from outputting that and return
> error 22.
>
> This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where
> non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when
> authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).
>
> See also --fail-with-body.

Comment: This is really the best answer. I just updated curl on my container with the latest version using a pre-built binary and `--fail-with-body` worked flawlessly. Thank you.

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised to find both my laptop and my Jenkins agent already had a new enough version of curl. I realize it's a bit over two years old... but it wouldn't be uncommon for one or the other to be using a version that's 2-5 years old...

Comment: This is no proper answer, because the question was "response code other than 200" and not "response code >= 400".

Answer (score 100):

I was able to do it using a combination of flags:

```
curl --silent --show-error --fail URL
```

**--silent** hides the progress and error
**--show-error** shows the error message hidden by `--silent`
**--fail** returns an exit code > 0 when the request fails

Comment: This doesn't show server reply. I am not OP but I suspect he wanted to see any error message from the server which is returned in body. Besides an `--silent --show-error --fail` works the same as just `-f/--fail`.

Comment: Actually, `--fail` returns exit code `22`, [as documented](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-returns.html).

Comment: This doesn't catch HTTP 301 Move Permanently. curl still gave exit code 0.

Comment: @wisbucky 301 isn't an error, it's a redirection status code.  Errors are 4xx and 5xx status codes.

Comment: To be fair to @wisbucky, the original question states _"[...] if the HTTP status code is not 200"_. No mention of "error" anywhere prior.

Comment: @M.Justin According to curl man-page: This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where  non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).

Comment: @waste It isn't the same as `--fail` alone; `--silent --show-error --fail` gets rid of the progress indicators

Answer (score 14):

I ended up with this based on [Dennis's answer](https://superuser.com/a/590170/176905), a quick one-liner that fails for non-200 status codes while retaining the output (to `stderr`):

```bsh
[ $(curl ... -o /dev/stderr -w "%{http_code}") -eq 200 ]
```

Comment: Sometimes the best answer is not the accepted one or the one with most votes. This one works cross platform as on macos you do not get the newest curl that has the `--fail-with-body`... same for lots of other platforms. Ugly, but works.

Comment: This is the best one that works for 301

Answer (score 13):

Yes there is a way to do it but is far from obvious as it involves 3 curl options:

```
curl -s --fail --show-error https://httpbin.org/status/200 > /dev/null
curl -s --fail --show-error https://httpbin.org/status/401 > /dev/null
curl -s --fail --show-error https://httpbin.org/status/404 > /dev/null
curl -s --fail --show-error https://bleah-some-wrong-host > /dev/null
```

This assures that success (0) happens only when curl end-us with final `2xx` return code and that `stdout` gets the body and that any errors would be displayed to stderr.

Please note that curl documentation may confuse you a little bit because it mentions that --fail could succeed for some 401 codes. Based on tests that is not true, at least not when used with --show-error at the same time.

So far I was unable to find any case where curl will return success when it was not a http-succeds with these options.

Comment: is this essentially the same answer as Ricardo Souza's?

Answer (score 4):

I recently also needed something like this but I also wanted to print the output at all times. I used the http_code extraction and grep to achieve this.

```bash
out=$(curl -H"Content-Type: application/json"  -w '\nstatus_code=%{http_code}\n' -s http://localhost:4040${uri} -d "${body}")
code=$(echo ${out}|grep status_code|awk -F"=" '{print $2}')
echo ${out}
if [[ ${code} -ge 400 ]];
then
    exit 2;
fi;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is based on @Dennis's solution, but shows the output only on error (return code not `200`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Create temp file, readable and writable only by current user and root
SCRATCH=$( umask 0077; mktemp -t tmp.XXXXXXXXXX )

# Cleanup temp file on script exit
function cleanup_on_exit {
    rm -f "$SCRATCH"
}
trap cleanup_on_exit EXIT

# Perform curl call
HTTP_CODE=$( curl -s -o "$SCRATCH" -w '%{http_code}' your..stuff..here )

# Analyze HTTP return code
if [ ${HTTP_CODE} -ne 200 ] ; then
    cat "${SCRATCH}"
    exit 1
fi
```

Alternative HTTP return code handling, where `2XX` is OK:

```bash
# Analyze HTTP return code
if [ ${HTTP_CODE} -lt 200 ] || [ ${HTTP_CODE} -gt 299 ] ; then
    cat "${SCRATCH}"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why not use a file descriptor or a fifo instead of a temp file? Seems a little more... unix-y.

Comment: Great suggestion, @ErikE. Why don't you write an answer that shows us how to do it? :)

Comment: @Jake I wish I had the time for that!

Comment: @ErikE Everything in Unix/Linux/BSD "is a file", even a FIFO. The argumentation (`"more unix-y"`) seems logical first, and I'd like to see such a variant, but without a working example it's just an eyewash.

Comment: @t0r0X Okay then. I just don't like using global temp files in a directory accessible to other processes. Time and again, this creates problems.

Comment: I did notice something else. You can be POSIX compliant instead of using bash-isms: `if [ $HTTP_CODE -lt 200] || [ $HTTP_CODE -gt 299 ]; then ... fi`.

Comment: @ErikE Thanks for the suggestion, I changed the `if` statements to be POSIX compatible. Sidenote: I tried the past 20+ years to be POSIX compatible, but some time ago I surrendered to the sweetness of BASH and ZSH syntax extensions :-)

Comment: @ErikE I fixed the issue of the temp file being readable by other users, see the `umask 0077`.

Answer (score 2):

Here was my solution - it uses `jq` and assumes the body is json

```bsh
#  this code adds a statusCode field to the json it receives and then jq squeezes them together
# curl 7.76.0 will have curl --fail-with-body and thus eliminate all this
  local result
  result=$(
    curl -sL -w ' { "statusCode": %{http_code}} ' -X POST "${headers[@]}" "${endpoint}" \
      -d "${body}"  "$curl_opts" | jq -ren '[inputs] | add'
  )
#   always output the result
  echo "${result}"
#  jq -e will produce an error code if the expression result is false or null - thus resulting in a
# error return code from this function naturally. This is much preferred rather than assume/hardcode
# the existence of a error object in the body payload
  echo "${result}" | jq -re '.statusCode >= 200 and .statusCode < 300' > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried to use the approaches shown here but kept having an error because curl was providing the response_code as `000401` when  it should be `401` (curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0). Bash converts `000401` to `257` so trying to test for `>=200` and `<=299` wasn't reliable.

I end up with this function:

```sh
function curl_custom() {
    local RESPONSE_CODE
    RESPONSE_CODE=$(curl -v --silent --output /dev/stderr --write-out "%{response_code}" "$@")

    # Remove leading zeros (if any) to prevent bash interpreting result as octal
    RESPONSE_CODE=${RESPONSE_CODE##+(0)}

    if (( RESPONSE_CODE >= 200 )) && (( RESPONSE_CODE <= 299 )) ; then
        echo "INFO - Got response ${RESPONSE_CODE}"
    else
        echo "ERROR - Request failed with ${RESPONSE_CODE}"
        return 127
    fi
}
```

Examples on usage:

```sh
curl_custom example.com example.com
curl_custom -X PUT -U user:pass file.json example.com/api
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

to also write the error body to stderr, parse the response headers in bash, and then, depending on the response status, send the response body to stdout (`cat`) or to stderr (`cat >&2`)

```sh
curl -s --fail-with-body -D - -o - https://httpbin.dev/status/418 | {
  status=
  while read -r header; do
    header="${header:0: -1}" # strip trailing "\r"
    #echo "header: ${header@Q}" >&2 # debug
    if [ -z "$status" ]; then
      status=${header#* } # first header has status
      status=${status%% *}
      continue
    fi
    [ -z "$header" ] && break # end of headers
  done
  #echo "status: $status" >&2 # debug
  if [ "${status:0:1}" = 2 ]; then
    cat # write body to stdout
  else
    cat >&2 # write body to stderr
  fi
} |
cat >/dev/null
```

this will parse the response status from the first header line, for example `HTTP/2 200` or `HTTP/1.1 400 OK`