# What's the exit code for "curl -I" when not HTTP 200?

Tags: python, html, curl, exit-code, http-status-codes

I want to check what HTTP status code is returned for an HTTP(S) URL. I don't care about content, so I just request head with
  curl -I $url
or
  curl --head $url

But what's the exit code I should check for, e.g. in [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)? In particular, do I get a non-zero exit code for HTTP 403?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`curl -I` will always return `0`, if it managed to produce an output with the HEAD. You have two alternatives.

The first is to use `curl -I --fail` [instead](https://superuser.com/a/657174/283120), and check for exit code `22`.

If you're doing this in a Python script, it could look like:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call(['curl', '-I', '--fail', url])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    if e.returncode == 22:
        (do something)
```

The second is to [actually ask just the HTTP status code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22078683/4145951), like this:

```
$ curl -s -I -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' $bad-url
403
```

Answer (score 1):

If you truly just want the HTTP status codes from a python script, you may want to check out the 'requests' library:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

```python
#Prints status code:    
import requests
r = requests.get('http://superuser.com')
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: True, though the question was about curl only for other reasons.