# How to detect in Bash when Curl fails downloading non-existent file?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, curl

I'm using `curl` to download a zip file. `curl` is called from a `bash` script:

```
curl --user joedoe http://1.2.3.4/files/joedoe.zip -o /tmp/downloaded.zip
```

I'd like to detect when the target zip file does not exist.

I tried

```
if ! [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then
  echo "ERROR: problem with Curl."
  exit 1
fi ;
```

but it seems that `$?` returned by `curl` is `0`, so I am unable to detect when the zip files does not exist.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate of [*Can I make cURL fail with an exitCode different than 0 if the HTTP status code is not 200?*](https://superuser.com/q/590099/432690) The [most upvoted answer](https://superuser.com/a/657174/432690) (i.e. most upvoted when I'm writing this) advises `-f`. This solution will catch `4xx` or `5xx` HTML error codes, but not `301 Moved Permanently`. In your case the HTML error code may or may not be `301`.

If I were you, I would capture and analyze this code. Fortunately your `curl` uses `-o` and writes to a regular file, not to stdout; so we can use stdout for our extra task. `-w` is what you need:

```
http_code="$(curl --user joedoe -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /tmp/downloaded.zip http://1.2.3.4/files/joedoe.zip)"
exit_status="$?"
```

Now you have `$exit_status` *and* `$http_code` to analyze. Decide if you want `-f` and build the logic of your script accordingly. Basically [you want `$http_code` to be `200`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success). Even if it's `200`, check anyway if `$exit_status` is `0`. Imagine the link is good, but you cannot write to `/tmp/downloaded.zip` (maybe somebody put a rogue file there in the hope you will use it). This is an example case when you can get `200` from the server and still an error (non-zero `$exit_status`) from `curl`.

---

Even if `$exit_status` is `0` and `$http_code` is `200`, you may still want to check if `/tmp/downloaded.zip` is a valid zip file. A basic test may be the exit status of:

```
[ "$(file -b --mime-type /tmp/downloaded.zip)" = application/zip ]
```

(if your `file` supports these options). A "full" test is by checking the exit status of:

```
unzip -t /tmp/downloaded.zip
```

Comment: Too complicated for my use case maybe, didn't have time to try.